# $x\in [0,1]$ and $n\in N$ $\implies$ $\left| \frac{1-2xn}{n^2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x\in [0,1]$ and $n\in N$. According to the solutions manual this is true:

$$\left| \frac{1-2xn}{n^2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$

How can I see this is true ?

Comment: for since it is linear, the maximum of LHS will be achieved at endpoints, i.e. $x=0$ or $x=1$

Comment: @Avatar I mean $2xn-1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0 \le x \le 1$,
$0 \ge 1-2xn \ge 1-2n$.
So, $|1-2xn| \le 2n-1$.

We thus want to show that
$\frac{2n-1}{n^2} \le \sqrt{n}$
or $2n-1 \le n^{2.5}$.

Looking at the $2n-1$, I think of
$(n-1)^2 = n^2-2n+1$.
Since $(n-1)^2 \ge 0$,
$0 \le (n-1)^2 = n^2-2n+1$
or $2n-1 \le n^2$
and since $n^2 \le n^{2.5}$ we are done.

Comment: This shows a different inequality than the one asked.

Answer (score 2):

$$|\dfrac{1-2xn}{n^2}|= \max(|\dfrac1{n^2}|,|\dfrac{1-2n}{n^2}|)$$ As $n\in \mathbb{N}\; \;2n-1\geq1$
$$|\dfrac{1-2xn}{n^2}|\leq\dfrac{2n-1}{n^2}$$
Also,
$$\frac d{dn}\dfrac{2n-1}{n^{1.5}}=\dfrac{2n^{1.5}-3n^{1.5}+1.5n^{0.5}}{n^3}\leq0\;n>1.5 $$  Also the inequality is true for 1, and 3
So,
$$ \dfrac{2n-1}{n^2}\leq\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\; n\neq2$$

Comment: I don't understand how $2n-1\geq1 \implies \dfrac{2n-1}{n^{1.5}}\leq1$.

Comment: It doesn't. I got the 2nd result by taking a derivative. $2n-1\geq 1$ is for the previous step.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is wrong for $n=2$: if $x=1$, the LHS is $\frac34=.750$ and the RHS is $\frac1{\sqrt2}=.707$.

For $n=1$ and every $n\geqslant3$, the inequality holds.